# Emscripten call to SDL_Init freezes Browser Textinput

Tags: sdl, emscripten

I am currently crosscompiling a Sprite Engine under mingw.
Therefore i have 2 Questions.

The behavior of SDL is Emulated by Emscripten through the WebGL Layer.
i don't even have to link the SDL libraries when compiling with emcc.

1. Question is:

   If i initalize my App Like this:

   ```
   if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO) == -1)return -1;
   SDL_Surface *screen= SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480,  24, SDL_SWSURFACE);
   SDL_FillRect(screen, 0, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 0, 0));
   SDL_Flip(screen);
   ```

   then i am NOT able to put text into a textfield of the Browser, but i am getting the SDL_Events.
   All other Browser Inputs like checkboxes or selectboxes are working.

   If initialize my App like this (Emscripten works also without SDL_Init!):

   ```
   SDL_Surface *screen= SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480,  24, SDL_HWSURFACE);
   SDL_FillRect(screen, 0, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 0, 0));
   SDL_Flip(screen);
   ```

   then i am able to put tet into the browser textfield but i am not getting SDL_Events.

   **Is there a workaround to get the Browser Text Input Fields and SDL_Events working?**
2. Question

   This line of code compiled on my WIN32 System fills the screen blue

   ```
   SDL_FillRect(screen,NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 0, 0));
   ```

   the same line compiled with Emscripten fills the screen red.

   **Is there a way to switch the SDL colors in Emscripten or in the SDL headers?**

Answer (score 4):

From your native code, add this before the SDL_CreateWindow call:

```
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_EMSCRIPTEN_KEYBOARD_ELEMENT, "#canvas");
```

More info here: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_EMSCRIPTEN_KEYBOARD_ELEMENT

Answer (score 2):

Emscripten, by default, captures all user events to the page. This makes sense for a fullscreen game for example. In your use case, you probably want to modify Emscripten's SDL_Init to not listen to key events, or change its receiveEvent return value.

Comment: Thank you Alon, yes indeed it makes sense that this behavior is intended in a browser environment.

Comment: In fact someone else stumbles over the same issue i had with the colors and cross compiling: equal what you bytes per pixel you set in SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480,  24, SDL_HWSURFACE); you will get the pixel format of the browser in emscripten

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  For me, doing this fixed it:

Module['doNotCaptureKeyboard'] = true;